# Optional selection from 5 million+ lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a 5 million plus line plain text file. Windows Notepad can't do anything and gets stuck when double clicking the file. Notepad++ is able to open the file though, even with 5M lines.
I want to split the file into 10 single text files - i.e. the first 50K lines would be in an individual file, and so the next and next.

The problem is that when I Ctrl+G and go to the 50kth line, I have to hold shift, pressing the up arrow until the first 50k lines are selected. It takes several minutes. Is there any easier way to split up the files?

Comment: This may be a task better handled by the command line.

Answer (score 7):

Shift-control-home will highlight from the current position to the top of the file.

Comment: wow this is indeed a shortcut for me,,even though it takes time,, i think it's much faster than just pressing shift+up and wait..

Comment: The "real" question should be "is there a utility that will split a text file into smaller files based on a number of lines".  I think that would be a better solution to the underlying requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You might give **SPLIT** in [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) a try. Simply:

```
split --lines=50000 YourInputFile.dat OutputFile.
```

will generate:

```
OutputFile.aa
OutputFile.ab
OutputFile.ac
OutputFile.ad
 .
 .
```

each with 50,000 records. The final file will contain the remainder.

Comment: thanks,  i really want to try what you said, but i know so little about gnuwin32..

Comment: It can be a simple as downloading the core utilities (from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and installing. Then, invoke split from wherever you've installed it.